# analysing stability of a measurement over time

Tags: statistics, visualization, descriptive-statistics

I have some sensor data (actually many different sensors about 90 of them) and I have their readings over some time course. I was wondering on a couple of things:

1: What metrics can I use to assess if the measurements are stable across the time period. Is there something more I can do besides calculating the standard deviation which might give me an indication of the stability of the measurement?

2: What is the best way to visualise the data. So, I have about 90 sensors and I can compute something like box-plot for the various sensor measurements to visualise the distributions but my issue is that the sensors have different scale and I was wondering what might be an effective visualisation tool.

For example, I could have one sensor measuring temperature and one measuring pressure and the reading could be:

```
temp        pressure
51          9.3
49          9.2
50          9.3
```

So the scales are different. How can one visualise these sort of different  data types in one graphic as this could be much more efficient in communicating the information. I wonder if there is a way to use this graphic and the measurement stability metrics to indicate quickly if one or more sensors are misbehaving.

Comment: What does stability mean to you; deviation from the mean?

Comment: That is what I was thinking and bear with me as I am new to this but does this assume a Gaussian distribution to be reliable? Should that be check first? I am basically looking at hints on how a data scientist might go about exploring this sort of measurement datasets?

Comment: Good question. So look at the distribution of the [residual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors_and_residuals). You can use a moving average.

Comment: 2. You can use x-y plot. Take temp as your X and Pressure as Y.
Here you can see the dependency of the 2 factors. You can also calculate Pearson Correlation if the 2 are really related.